# permutate all the values in python list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list `a = [1, 1, 1]`, and I want to permutate the `a` in different manner, the result maybe like
`[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]`. How can I do it in efficient manner?

Comment: What would be the result with `a = [2, 1, 1]` ?

Comment: I only want it to be 0 and 1, because I have to convert it to binary value after this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question indicates you have a list of length `N`(3, in this case, [1, 1, 1]), and you want every possible combination if the element at each position can be 0 or 1. (your question is confusing, as you aren't really permuting [1,1,1]).

What you want is `itertools.product`, documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). It takes a list of iterables, and creates every combination of an item from the first iterable, the second iterable, etc. So in this case we could achieve the goal with:

```
> import itertools
> zero_and_one = [0, 1]
> combinations = itertools.product(zero_and_one, zero_and_one, zero_and_one)
> print(list(combinations))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Happy Coding!